# Exibir imagens que estão em outra tabela

Tags: php, banco-de-dados

Olá, tenho as duas tabelas abaixo:

Tabela IMAGENS

```
id_imagens  | diretorio_imagem | post_id
       1        imagem1.jpg          1
       2        imagem2.jpg          1
       3        imagem3.jpg          1
       4        imagem4.jpg          1
       5        imagem5.jpg          2
       6        imagem6.jpg          2
       7        imagem7.jpg          2
       8        imagem8.jpg          2
```

Tabela POSTS

```
id_post   |          slug        |   titulo     
 1           titulo_do_post         Titulo do Post 
 2           titulo_do_post_2       Titulo do Post 2
```

Na pagina de post.php eu busco pelo slug da tabela posts:

```
$slug = $_GET['slug'];
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE slug=:slug");
     $stmt->execute(array(":slug"=>$_GET['slug']));
     while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH))
{
print utf8_encode($row['titulo']);

}
```

O código acima pega o slug da url e busca no DB.

www.meusite.com.br/titulo_do_post_2

O código php acima vai pegar o trecho titulo_do_post_2 e buscar no DB algo identico.
Até aqui ok, o próximo passo é através do slug descobrir qual o id do post e com o id do post ai sim fazer um inner join

Eu gostaria de pelo slug conseguir saber o id_post e retornar da tabela IMAGENS que tem o post_id idêntico para exibir todas imagens

Deu bug não sei como fazer, inner join ainda tenho muita dificuldade para usar

Agradeço ajuda

Answer (score 0):

Você não precisa usar join nesse caso, tente:

```
SELECT i.diretorio_imagem
FROM Posts p, Imagens i
WHERE p.slug='titulo_do_post_2' AND i.post_id = p.id_post;
```

Vai retornar o diretório de todas imagens com cujo `post_id` é igual ao `id_post` do post de slug `titulo_do_post_2`.

O código ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
<?php

    $servername = "";
    $username = "";
    $password = "";
    $database = "";
    $dbport = 3306;
    $db = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database, $dbport);

    $slug = $_GET['slug'];

    $sql = "SELECT i.diretorio_imagem FROM POSTS p, IMAGENS i WHERE p.slug='$slug' AND i.post_id = p.id_post";

    $results = $db->query($sql);

    while($row = $results->fetch_row()) {
        // Mostrando o diretório das imagens
        echo "<p>" . $row[0] . "</p>";
    }

    $db->close();
?>
```

Comment: obrigada @CosmeLopes mas não aparece erro nem imprime as informações, simplesmente fica em branco

Comment: Editei a resposta com um exemplo de código, dá uma olhada.

Comment: o titulo esta sendo impresso mais varias vezes conforme a quantidade de imagens, deveria imprimir o titulo uma unica vez seguido das imagens

Comment: A ideia é te mostrar como obter os dados. Agora você tem **todas as imagens relacionadas ao post**. Como você vai utilizar a lista na sua aplicação fica a seu critério.

Answer (score 0):

Como você está usando PDO, substitua pelo código abaixo.
No resultado virão todos os dados necessários em uma única consulta.

```
$slug = $_GET['slug']; 
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * 
                      FROM posts, imagens 
                      WHERE posts.id_post = imagens.post_id 
                      AND slug=:slug"); 
$stmt->execute(array(":slug"=>$_GET['slug'])); 
while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH)) 
{ //print utf8_encode($row['titulo']); 
print_r($row);
}
```

Comment: Obrigada @BillRocha, mas o titulo esta sendo repetido a cada nova imagem, o correto seria o titulo uma unica vez e todas imagens também